# Cycle in C# can't get this to end >.<

Tags: c#, loops

Right now I'm trying to make it so I've got 1 character and 3 enemies if my character dies it's supposed to give game over or something but I can't make it to work (if enemies die it works tho I don't know why).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
        bool Exit = false;
        bool CharDead = false;

        Heroe Heroe1 = p.ElementAt(0);
        Enemigo Enemigo1 = l.ElementAt(0);
        Enemigo Enemigo2 = l.ElementAt(1);
        Enemigo Enemigo3 = l.ElementAt(2);
        a.Agregar(comienza);
        List<Items> item = new List<Items>();
        do
        {
            if (Heroe1.HP > 0)
                AccionesHeroe1(l, p);

            if (Enemigo1.HP > 0)
                AccionesEnemigo1(l, p);

            if (Enemigo2.HP > 0)
                AccionesEnemigo2(l, p);

            if (Heroe1.HP > 0)
                AccionesHeroe1(l, p);
            else
                CharDead = true;
            if (Enemigo3.HP > 0)
                AccionesEnemigo3(l, p);

            if (Heroe1.HP <= 0)
            {
                CharDead = true;
            }
            if (Enemigo1.HP <= 0 && Enemigo2.HP <= 0 && Enemigo3.HP <= 0)
            {
                Exit = true;
            }

        } while (Exit == false || CharDead == false);
```

Comment: >.< (Nice expression you got there :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ending condition is:

```
 (Exit == false || CharDead == false);
```

This will only exit when CharDead **AND** Exit are both true.

You probably want to rework it to be:

```
 (Exit == false && CharDead == false);
```

This way, as soon as Exit is not false or CharDead is not false, you'll exit.

Comment: OOOOOOOO I DIDNT KNEW && worked that way THANK YOU VERY MUCH XD

Comment: Also, it is more stylin' to say "(!Exit && !CharDead)".  The long way reads "if the comparison of exit to false is true and the comparison of chardead to false is true", which seems needlessly verbose. The short way reads "if exit is not true and chardead is not true".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change your while loop expression to

```
do
{
} while(!Exit && !CharDead)
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
while (Exit == false || CharDead == false);
```

to

```
while (Exit == false && CharDead == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work too, right?

```
while(!(Exit || CharDead));
```